# Kafka - is it possible to alter cluster size while keeping the change transparent to Producers and Consumers?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am investigating on Kafka to assess its suitability for our use case. Can you please help me understand how flexible is Kafka with altering the size of an existing cluster?

I am investigating on Kafka to assess its suitability for our use case. Can you please help me understand how flexible is Kafka with adding brokers to an existing cluster without tearing down the cluster? Is there anything to be taken care of when doing this?

Comment: IIUC, there's no way to change partition size dynamically. But you can just choose a high enough partition size to begin with; fewer consumers will be able to handle it fine, and adding more will result in rebalancing, so it should have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

> Adding servers to a Kafka cluster is easy, just assign them a unique
>   broker id and start up Kafka on your new servers. However these new
>   servers will not automatically be assigned any data partitions, so
>   unless partitions are moved to them they won't be doing any work until
>   new topics are created. So usually when you add machines to your
>   cluster you will want to migrate some existing data to these machines.

Refer [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_cluster_expansion)
 Kafka supports:

- Expanding your cluster
- Automatically migrating data to new machines
- Custom partition assignment and migration

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can increase the number of partitions of a topic using command line or `AdminClient` without restarting the cluster processes.

Example:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zk_host:port --alter --topic testtopic1 
   --partitions 20
```

Please be aware, that altering the partitions doesn't change the partitioning of existing topics.

Kafka only allows to increase the partitions but you can't decrease the partitions. If in case, you have to reduce the partitions, you need to delete and recreate the topic.

For your question "***what happens with producer/consumer behave for newly added partitions***"

Kafka has a property `metadata.max.age.ms` for producers and consumers which defaults to 300000.

***metadata.max.age.ms : The period of time in milliseconds after which we force a refresh of metadata even if we haven't seen any partition leadership changes to proactively discover any new brokers or partitions.***

After the given value, metadata are updated and any newly added partitions will be detected by the producers/consumers.